# Load gif in image view

Tags: android, load, imageview

In my application has a part that will grab images from a server. The problem is that while images are being loaded in the application that space remains vacant. How do I get that gif to warn the user that the image is being loaded?

Example: http://goo.gl/mwFCC

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a progress Bar(Custom Progress bar) in the vacant space and as soon as your image is downloaded remove it.

Create a Xml in Drawable as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="200" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

Now your progress bar will look like this

```
// Put this in Your vacant space
 <ProgressBar 
android:id="@+id/myId"
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate" 
        android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:layout_width="50dp">
</ProgressBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the remote image is being downloaded, show an animated GIF or some other kind of animation (e.g. using something like this http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.se/2010/09/gif-animation-in-android.html) in the view that should hold the remote image. Once the download is complete, notify the main thread and tell it to update the view with the downloaded image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the buit in android `ProgressDialog` to achieve this, For exemple use an `AsynchronousTask` to download the image on your onPreExecute() show your dialog on `doInBackground()`  process downloading and in `onPostExecute()` dismiss your dialog and display the result. You can also take a look at `frame animation` if you want to use custom dialog.